# Curl using Retrofit android

Tags: java, android, curl, retrofit

I upload an image to a server using curl -F datafile="@myIMage.png" http://www.myUrl.com/tools/index.php/testUpload/do_upload
I have to replicate this upload using an http call in android, I'm using retrofit and this is my code:

```
public static class NetworkClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myUrl.com/tools/index.php/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

public interface UploadAPIs {
    @Multipart
    @POST("/testUpload/do_upload")
    retrofit2.Call<SimpleAdapter> uploadImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part file, @Part("datafile") RequestBody requestBody);
}

    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(getApplicationContext());
            UploadAPIs uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(UploadAPIs.class);

            File file = new File(path); // the path where is stored the image

            RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
            MultipartBody.Part part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("datafile", "@"+file.getName(), fileReqBody);
            RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), "image-type");

            final retrofit2.Call call = uploadAPIs.uploadImage(part, description);

            call.enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                    Log.d("SICC", String.valueOf(call.request()));
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("FAIL", t.toString());
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

but in this way I can't post my photo to my server, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your api service class

```
@POST("/testUpload/do_upload")
@Multipart
Call<SimpleAdapter> uploadImage(@PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map);
```

put value to your hashmap

```
 HashMap hashMap = new HashMap<String, RequestBody>();
 RequestBody fileReqBody = RequestBody.create(
              MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), new File(path));
 hashMap.put("datafile\"; filename=\"image_" 
                          + System.currentTimeMillis() 
                          +".jpeg\"", fileReqBody);
```

call api method

```
Retrofit retrofit = NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient(getApplicationContext());
UploadAPIs uploadAPIs = retrofit.create(UploadAPIs.class);

final retrofit2.Call call = uploadAPIs.uploadImage(hashMap);

call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
                Log.d("SICC", String.valueOf(call.request()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("FAIL", t.toString());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please check your file and path.

Comment: This is the response: D/SICC: Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=404, message=Not Found, url=http://myUrl.com/testUpload/do_upload}

Comment: Please test your api link with postman. I think your api method is not exist.